# Setting the auth info in the Firebase Firestore simulator

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I've seen several examples online that show you being able to configure the auth instance to test role based access control, and the Firestore docs say you can, but don't see the same controls in the current UI.

> Cloud Firestore provides a rules simulator that you can use to test your ruleset. You can access the simulator from the Rules tab in the Cloud Firestore section of the Firebase console. The rules simulator lets you simulate authenticated and unauthenticated reads, writes, and deletes. When you simulate an authenticated request, you can build and preview authentication tokens from various providers. Simulated requests run against the ruleset in your editor, not your currently deployed ruleset.

[image: Screenshot of Firestore Rules Simulator]

Answer (score 0):

It appears this was a bug they have resolved.